# How to find the removed volume?

Tags: integration

The following problem was in a mathematical competition paper under integration part.

> A square hole of side length $2x$ is cut symmetrically through a sphere of radius $y$ ;$(y >x\sqrt{2})$. Find the volume removed.

Could anyone please give me a help? Thanks.

Comment: *[Here](http://www.lomont.org/Math/Papers/2004/Integral.pdf)* is a solution for your problem.